# dynamically change style for html helper in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

how can i change the style of html helper dynamically because in doing language change the font sizes are diferent for each and every language , so how can i change styles dynamically

```
  @Html.LabelFor(u => u.username)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.username)
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.username)


  @Html.LabelFor(u => u.username)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.password)
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.password)
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is something like this:

```
@Html.LabelFor(u => u.username, new {@class = "my-class"});
...

<style>
 .some-language {font: 1em;}
 .another-language {font: 2em;}
</style>

<script>
 ("#someButton").click(function(){
  $(".my-class").addClass("some-language");
})
...
</script>
```